# How should we handle spammers who recreate accounts after deletion?

Tags: support, spam

I've got a spammer by the name of **Jesse** who just keeps coming, even after several account deletions:

- https://superuser.com/users/162151/jesse
- https://superuser.com/users/162150/jesse
- https://superuser.com/users/162141/user162141

  *some links ♦moderator only*

This case appears to be resolved, but can something be done about this so that these types of spam attacks are prevented in the future?

Comment: Would "nuke em till they glow, then shoot them in the dark" be a little too drastic? ;p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We're on it - I've already destroyed one account, and suspended/messaged the other account.  I'm monitoring the flag queue as well.  He may have gotten another account, we're watching him.

Comment: Just updated the question for long-term relevance.

Comment: So how should I respond in future cases of this kind? What should I do? Should I just continue to just use the spam flag, use the free-text moderator flag, or do something else?

Comment: I would suggest using the spam flag, or use a regular flag and let us know this is a repeat spammer and to look at his profile/other posts... @DragonLord